# EF core 6 selecting null values despite where clause asking for not null

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have a Linq2Sql Query like this:

```
Parent.Include(p => p.Children)
  .Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.SomeNullableDateTime == null)
    && p.Children
        .Where(c => c.SomeNullableDateTime == null)
        .OrderBy(c => c.SomeInteger)
        .First()
        .SomeOtherNullableDateTime != null
  )
  .Select(p => p.Children
        .Where(c => c.SomeNullableDateTime == null)
        .OrderBy(c => c.SomeInteger)
        .First()
        .SomeOtherNullableDateTime)
  .ToList();
```

This worked fine until moving from EF core 5 to EF core 6.  With EF core 6 the result list contains some null values (which should not be the case because the where condition asks for not null).  Is there some breaking change / limitation in EF core 6 I'm not aware of or is this simply a bug?

Update: This is an excerpt of the output

[image]

Update 2: This is the generated SQL Statement

```
SELECT(
    SELECT TOP(1)[p1].[SomeOtherNullableDateTime]
    FROM[Children] AS[p1]
    WHERE([p].[Id] = [p1].[ParentId]) AND[p1].[SomeNullableDateTime] IS NULL
    ORDER BY[p1].[SomeInteger])
FROM[Parent] AS[p]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM[Children] AS [c]
    WHERE ([p].[Id] = [c].[ParentId]) AND[c].[SomeNullableDateTime] IS NULL) AND EXISTS(
   SELECT 1
   FROM[Children] AS [c0]
    WHERE ([p].[Id] = [c0].[ParentId]) AND[c0].[SomeNullableDateTime] IS NULL)
GO
```

So it looks like the problem is that **SomeOtherNullableDateTime** (which is supposed to be not null) is not even included in the where clause of the generated SQL.

Update 3: This is the SQL EF core 5 (correctly) generates

```
SELECT (
    SELECT TOP(1) [c].[SomeOtherNullableDateTime]
    FROM [Children] AS [c]
    WHERE ([p].[Id] = [c].[ParentId]) AND [c].[SomeNullableDateTime] IS NULL
    ORDER BY [c].[SomeInteger])
FROM [Parent] AS [p]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Children] AS [c0]
    WHERE ([p].[Id] = [c0].[ParentId]) AND [c0].[SomeNullableDateTime] IS NULL) AND (
    SELECT TOP(1) [c1].[SomeOtherNullableDateTime]
    FROM [Children] AS [c1]
    WHERE ([p].[Id] = [c1].[ParentId]) AND [c1].[SomeNullableDateTime] IS NULL
    ORDER BY [c1].[SomeInteger]) IS NOT NULL
GO
```

Comment: What's the generated SQL statement?

Comment: @StefanGolubović: I have added the generated sql statement to the question

Comment: i find it weird that you don't but the .First at the end of the statement.

Comment: Why `Include` and then `Select`? These two things don't play well together (most probably the `Include` is ignored). I would do just `Select` + `Where`.

Comment: @IvanStoev: The statement in real life does not have the include + select but only select + where.  I just created the above statement to create the output to prove my point.

Comment: @IvanStoev: I have updated my question to include the generated SQL from EF core 5 which did work as expected.

Comment: @René Sorry, my bad, haven't noticed `Where` is outside the `Include`.

Comment: @IvanStoev: I was just scratching my head trying to figure out what you were trying to say :-D

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking you are trying to use filtered include, which of course is ignored :) Let me try to reproduce it, although if what you are saying is true, then you have hit some EFC 6 bug and you have to go to their issue tracker.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Not related to the question but to your comment: Has Filtered Include been removed again in EF core 6? To my knowledge it works with EF core 5.

Comment: @IvanStoev: I have opened a ticket on GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26744

Comment: No, filtered include is not removed. But potentially is ignored along with the whole include call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The development team on GitHub has confirmed that there are two different bugs that cause these problems:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26744

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26756

Unfortunately they have stated that these bugs will not be fixed in the 6.0.1 release scheduled for december but earliest with another release scheduled for February 2022.

Since these bugs cause EF core 6 to quietly return wrong results and there is a good chance of many users messing up their data or making decisions based on wrong data (because no one will check all Linq2SQL queries for correct SQL generation !?) I recommend to not use EF core 6 for now!

This might be regarded as opinion-based but please don't delete this answer but leave it as a warning for fellow developers!

**Update:**
There are fixes for these issues now:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/27284

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/27292

They have been approved to be released with version 6.0.3 which is planned for March 2022.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like EF Core 6.0 query translation bug. The same happens if you use the "more natural" way of writing such query

```cs
var query = db.Set<Parent>()
    .Select(p => p.Children
        .Where(c => c.SomeNullableDateTime == null)
        .OrderBy(c => c.SomeInteger)
        .FirstOrDefault())
    .Where(c => c.SomeOtherNullableDateTime != null)
    .Select(c => c.SomeOtherNullableDateTime);
```

The generated SQL

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT TOP(1) [c0].[SomeOtherNullableDateTime]
    FROM [Child] AS [c0]
    WHERE ([p].[Id] = [c0].[ParentId]) AND [c0].[SomeNullableDateTime] IS NULL
    ORDER BY [c0].[SomeInteger])
FROM [Parent] AS [p]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Child] AS [c]
    WHERE ([p].[Id] = [c].[ParentId]) AND [c].[SomeNullableDateTime] IS NULL)
```

is also missing `IS NOT NULL` criteria, so you might include this scenario in the bug report.

The equivalent pattern (with `SelectMany` + `Take(1)` instead of `Select` + `FirstOrDefault()`)

```cs
var query = db.Set<Parent>()
    .SelectMany(p => p.Children
        .Where(c => c.SomeNullableDateTime == null)
        .OrderBy(c => c.SomeInteger)
        .Take(1))
    .Where(c => c.SomeOtherNullableDateTime != null)
    .Select(c => c.SomeOtherNullableDateTime);
```

(same as suggested at the meantime by @Svyatoslav), generates different SQL

```sql
SELECT [t0].[SomeOtherNullableDateTime]
FROM [Parent] AS [p]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [t].[ParentId], [t].[SomeNullableDateTime], [t].[SomeOtherNullableDateTime]
    FROM (
        SELECT [c].[ParentId], [c].[SomeNullableDateTime], [c].[SomeOtherNullableDateTime], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [c].[ParentId], [c].[SomeNullableDateTime] ORDER BY [c].[SomeInteger]) AS [row]
        FROM [Child] AS [c]
    ) AS [t]
    WHERE [t].[row] <= 1
) AS [t0] ON ([p].[Id] = [t0].[ParentId]) AND [t0].[SomeNullableDateTime] IS NULL
WHERE [t0].[SomeOtherNullableDateTime] IS NOT NULL
```

which has `IS NOT NULL` condition, but now the inner subquery looks wrong, since it selects every first child ordered by something, then applies `IS NULL` criteria, while the LINQ query requests to first apply the `IS NULL` criteria, then select the first child ordered by something. So you might include this use case in the bug report as well.

All these queries, including the one from the OP, work correctly (generate correct SQL) in EF Core 5.0.

Comment: Yeah critical bug in subquery optimization. They should not change Window search condition.

Comment: So we found two different issues in one SO question. Probably you have to create new issue for them.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev:  I have added your two examples to the GitHub Ticket (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26744)

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: The development team has confirmed two bugs related to these queries.  Unfortunately  they will not be fixed until next February the earliest.  I therefore wrote another answer as a warning for fellow developers.

Comment: @René Too bad. Although the case is a bit specific to "top N items in group" pattern, so I won't go too far and not recommend generally EFC 6.0 just because of this. But it's good to be known.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: I've asked on GitHub if the bugs are limited to the provided scenarios or if there might be other types of queries affected as well.  If and when I get an answer I'll include it in my answer.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: There are fixes for these issues now which will be released with 6.0.3. I've added the links to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While it can be regression, I would suggest to rewrite query in effective and more predictable way:

```cs
var query =
    from p in Parent
    from c in p.Children
        .Where(c.SomeNullableDateTime == null)
        .OrderBy(c => c.SomeInteger)
        .Take(1)
    where c.SomeOtherNullableDateTime != null
    select c.SomeOtherNullableDateTime;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as well (see my answer), so the bug seems to be more serious than it looks. Some messed up optimization I guess.