# Is it safe to mix .NET 6 with EF core 5

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Upon the release of .NET 6 I migrated my Blazor projects from .NET 5 to .NET 6.  The migration included moving from EF core 5 to EF core 6.  Unfortunately I found out that EF core 6 still has some bugs which render it useless for me (see [EF core 6 selecting null values despite where clause asking for not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70017594/ef-core-6-selecting-null-values-despite-where-clause-asking-for-not-null/)).
Therefore I moved back to v5 with the following packages

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore
- Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore

so basically all packages with "EntityFrameworkCore" in the name.  Everything else I left in the v6 versions and the project types are still .NET 6.

Is this safe, or should I go back to .NET 5 alltogether ?

Comment: Probably fine. I don't recall any breaking changes to EF's dependencies like Configuration, DI, Logging, etc. that would cause issues. But definitely upgrade to EF Core 6 once a patch is available.

Comment: @bricelam Thank you for your valuation of the matter.  The project went live a week ago and so far there seem to be no problems with the combination of .NET 6 and EF core 5